# Configurable product based on A LOT of attributes? Am I doing this right?

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have a customer who wants to use products in the same way configurable products works, pretty much.

The problem is that the customer would have to use a lot of different attributes. Let's say he's selling custom sized papers (for some reason haha), these comes then in... let's say maybe 30 different combonations of X x Y mm (10x20mm for example).

Then another product would also use mm, but no the same. Let's say he is also selling envelope in customer sizes, these does not match the sizes of the papers so I need another 50 combinations of sizes for this product.

Is this how it usually works? Or am I using wrong product type / wrong way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do Admin configuration for simple product as per below screenshot**

[image]

**customer will see**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Suman-PHP4U and Chirag Nandaniya for the answers. This will work perfectly for me! EDIT: Btw, do you happend to know how to show the SKU of the options on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem if you use configurable product it will be very confusing and you will find difficulty to adding this type of product using configurable product. As you have 30 to 50 attributes.

Best option for you would be simple product with custom option.

Comment: Simple Product with custom option? What is that? Any resource/help/guide for that kind of stuff? (I'm not a master Magento dev yet ;) )